# Get all documents where document ID contains my string

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase collection, and my documents ID are like this :

- User1-User2
- User1-User3
- User2-User4
- User4-User1

In my Flutter app, I want to get only the documents where the document ID contains "User1".

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to use Algolia, which is an external service allowing to do what I wanted to do. It's really easy to use and really practical ^^ I posted samples of my data into Algolia, and the research worked perfectly ^^

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

While it **is** possible to search for documents where the ID *starts with* a certain value, it is **not** possible to search for document IDs that *contain* a certain value.

If you need this functionality, the typical solution is to create an additional collection where you map the user ID to the relevant document IDs.